# Lexmark Z715 Ink Jet printer program for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, lexmark-printer

Where can I get a driver for a Lexmark Z715 ink jet printer? Lexmark can't help me.  What I don't understand is that I've been using this printer in this computer for 7-8 months, but for some reason I lost it and now can't get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows Vista 64-Bit Driver from here - You may have to install and use it in Compatibility Mode -

http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=product&linkSelected=node0&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_US#1

Answer (score 0):

I have E250d which is really old and I use it with Win 8.1 Pro 64-bit. I downloaded Lexmark universal print driver installation package. Try it and let me know if it help you.

Try this: http://support.lexmark.com/index?docLocale=fr_FR&page=content&id=DR22598&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_US